# Why will my Google Map API Ver3 Not allow me to display a marker, yet it will render markers in directions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that I am working on.  I am new to JS and Map API.  I found a Demo and am modifying it to meet my needs.
My issue is that the Map works.  It centers on the correct location but will not render a marker when initialized.  It will, however, render markers when driving directions are requested.
I have read everything, everywhere until my eyes hurt, and still cannot seem to grasp where in the code to put the marker.  When I put it in the code where I think it should go it does not render.

I have a fiddle that has all the code in it.  It would be awesome if someone could take a look at it and point out where I should add the marker so that it renders on Map Initialization

The Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hughesjoseph/nADJK/

I have tried to put the marker in this function as I believe it renders the initial map.

```
                mapSetup = function () {

                map = new google.maps.Map($Selectors.mapCanvas, {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531),

                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },

                    panControl: true,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                    },

                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                    },

                    scaleControl: true,
                    streetViewControl: true,
                    overviewMapControl: true,

                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                autoCompleteSetup();
                directionsSetup();
                trafficSetup();
            }, // mapSetup Ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a marker right after you initialize `map` variable, so you `mapSetup` function would look like this:

```
mapSetup = function () {
    map = new google.maps.Map($Selectors.mapCanvas, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531),

        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },

        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },

        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },

        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531),
        map: map
    });

    autoCompleteSetup();
    directionsSetup();
    trafficSetup();
}, // mapSetup Ends
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nADJK/10/

Comment: Freakin awesome.  Thank you.  I was pulling my hair out over that.